# Usar variable en messagebox?

Tags: tkinter, messagebox

tengo este pequeño codigo y deseo que en messagebox (mg.showinfo) se lea la variable de saldo pero no logro adjuntar texto y la variable, alguna solución?

```
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

saldo=5000000


def deposito():
    global table
    global operation
    global x

    window.withdraw()
    table=Toplevel()
    table.title("BANCO AUTÓNOMO")
    table.geometry("500x800+200+50")
    table.config(bg="steelblue")
    tt=Label(table, text="DEPÓSITO",bg="steelblue", fg="lemonchiffon", font=("FIXEDSYS", 30))
    tt.pack(anchor="nw")

    etiquetaDeposito = Label(table, text="¿CUANTO DESEA DEPOSITAR?", font=("FIXEDSYS", 15))
    etiquetaDeposito.place(x=100, y=300)
    x=IntVar()
    operation=Entry(table, textvariable=x, width=15)
    operation.place(x=310, y=300)
    botond = Button(table, text="DEPOSITAR", bd=3, bg="ghostwhite", fg="black", width=10, font=("FIXEDSYS"), command=sumar)
    botond.place(x=310, y=330)

def sumar():
    global saldo
    global x

    saldo=saldo + x.get()
    operation.delete(0,END)
    mb.showinfo("DEPOSITADO", "SU NUEVO MONTO ES (saldo)")
```

No logro hacer que en el cuadro de texto se agrege la variable, existe algún error? (El código está cortado ya que es un código de más de 300 lineas)

Answer (score 1):

No puedes pasarle a secas un string a un widget de Tkinter, si lo notas todos los argumentos que reciben los métodos de Tkinter son [kwargs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). Obviamente no estás logrando ver el mensaje, ya que la concatenación del string y la variable es errónea, además de la manera en que pretendes utilizar el string como mensaje.

En está [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html), te proveen la sintaxis correcta para definir el mensaje en cuestión:

> **Information message box**: `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=None, **options)`

Como puedes ver la manera correcta de definir el mensaje es haciendo uso del `kwarg message`. Un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb 

root = tk.Tk()

mb.showinfo(root,message = "mensaje")

root.mainloop()
```

Se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Solución:**

Para obtener el resultado que esperas se debe de hacer casting al `get()` de `x`, y aplicar lo mencionado anteriormente.

```
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

def sumar():
    global saldo
    global x

    saldo = saldo + int(x.get()) #Los 'Entry' retornan un string, hay que hacer casting
    operation.delete(0,END)

    mb.showinfo(message = f"DEPOSITADO, SU NUEVO MONTO ES {saldo}") #Una concatenación correcta
```

**Nota:** Solo es la función que te da problemas xD

Espero te haya servido. :)